Can't remember the movie (about a nuclear submarine)
I remember a movie about a nuclear submarine. They received some message about some escalating situation (or something like that) then the outside transmissions stopped. They assumed the worst and were ready to fire their nuclear arsenal, but there was an uprising on board and they didn't fire. In the end it turns out it was the right call.
The movie was very good and I am pretty sure it's a well known movie, but I can't remember its name. Does this sound familiar to anyone? Does someone know what the movie is?

It sounds like it is based on the actual story of the Russian submarine off Cuba in the Cuban Missile Crisis.

Is it Crimson Tide?
From Wikipedia:

[...]
Alabama eventually receives an Emergency Action Message, ordering the launch of ten of its missiles against the Russian nuclear installation, based on satellite information that the Russians' missiles are being fueled. Before Alabama can launch, a second message arrives but is cut off by the attack of a Russian Akula-class submarine loyal to Radchenko.
The radio is damaged in the attack and is unable to decode the second message. With the last confirmed order being to launch, Captain Ramsey decides to proceed. Hunter refuses to concur as is procedurally required, because he believes the partial second message may be a retraction. [...]
After several tense minutes, communications are restored and they finally see the full message from the second transmission. It is a retraction ordering that the missile launch be aborted because Radchenko's rebellion has been quelled. [...]

